# How to apply Angular.Copy

Tags: angularjs

I have below code

```
var myctrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{value: 1, name:'Nitin'},{value: 2, name:'Vikas'},{value: 3, name:'xxx'}];
    $scope.itemEdit1 = $scope.items;
    $scope.itemEdit2 = $scope.items.name;
};
```

I want to copy only name to itemEdit2

Comment: so basically, you want to copy all name values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.itemEdit2 = $scope.items[0].name;`

If you interesting to copy all names, it should be like:

```
 $scope.itemEdit2 = [];

 $scope.items.forEach(function(v, i) { 
    $scope.itemEdit2.push({name: v.name});  // or just push(v.name);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks but it only copy first value, I want all the value